# Modules over Dedekind domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have been reading the book Algebraic Number Theory by J.W.S. Cassels & A. Frohlich. In this book module index is defined and written without proof that for finitely generated $R$-module $M$ and $N$, M $\simeq N$  if and only if module index $[M:N]$ is principal fractional ideal. It is trivial if M $\simeq $ N, module index $[M:N]$ is principal, but I don't know how to show the other direction. It is in Chapter I,section 3 (Modules and Bilinear Forms near proposition 2)(In my book page 10). The following is detailed settings.

$R$ is Dedekind ring, $K$ is its quotient field and $U$ is vector space over $K$, $M,N$ are $R$-submodules which span $U$. $N \subset M$ is NOT assumed. Module index is defined as follows. For each prime ${\mathfrak p}$, there exist isomorphism $l:M_{\mathfrak p}\rightarrow N_{\mathfrak p}$,  then $[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$ is defined as $R\det(l):=[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$.Then module index is defined by $[M,N]R_{\mathfrak p}:=[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$ (This is fractional ideal of $R$)
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you clarify the setup? Is $N\subset M$? What kind of ring is $R$?

Comment: $R$ is Dedekind ring, $K$ is its quotient field and $U$ is vector space over $K$, $M,N$ are $R$-submodules which span $U$. $N \subset M$ is NOT assumed. Module index is defined as follows. For each prime ${\mathfrak p}$, there exist isomorphism $l:M_{\mathfrak p}\rightarrow N_{\mathfrak p}$,  then $[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$ is defined as $R\det(l):=[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$.Then module index is defined by $[M,N]R_{\mathfrak p}:=[M_{\mathfrak p},N_{\mathfrak p}]$ (This is fractional ideal of $R$)

Comment: I don't understand... why is there a map $M_{\mathfrak p}\to N_{\mathfrak p}$? Do you have a specific map $M\to N$?

Comment: I understand the definition as follows: For all but finitely many prime ideals $P$ we have $M_P=N_P$. Take any prime $Q$ with $M_Q\ne N_Q$. Since $R_Q$ is a DVR the finitely generated modules $M_Q,N_Q$ are free. For free modules the index is already defined. This is a non-zero fractional ideal of $R_Q$ and hence of the form $(QR_Q)^{n_Q}$. Now define the Index of $M,N$ over $R$ as the product of the $Q^{n_Q}$ over the prime ideals $Q$ such that $M_Q\ne N_Q$.

Comment: Exactly Mr leoli1 's comments.